# PHP / ICAL / Google Calendar

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I'm trying to get an ical feed working with Google Calendar and I just can't seem to get it right. I'm using the PHP iCalcreator class (http://www.kigkonsult.se/iCalcreator/index.php) and here's the code I'm using:

```
<?php

require_once APP_ROOT . '/lib/icalcreator.class.php';

$user = new User;
$user->Get(1);

$v = new vcalendar(); // create a new calendar instance
$v->setConfig('unique_id', 'Domain ' . $user->id); // set Your unique id
$v->setProperty('method', 'PUBLISH'); // required of some calendar software
$v->setProperty('X-WR-CALNAME;VALUE=TEXT', 'My Calendar');
$v->setProperty('X-WR-CALDESC', 'The description');

$tasks = $user->GetTasks();

foreach ($tasks as $task) {

    $vevent = new vevent(); // create an event calendar component
    $year = date('Y', strtotime($task->due));
    $month = date('m', strtotime($task->due));
    $day = date('d', strtotime($task->due));
    $hour = date('H', strtotime($task->due));
    $min = date('i', strtotime($task->due));
    $sec = date('s', strtotime($task->due));

    $vevent = new vevent();
    $vevent->setProperty('dtstart', array('year'=> $year, 'month'=> $month, 'day'=> $day, 'hour'=> $hour, 'min'=> $min, 'sec'=> $sec));
    $vevent->setProperty('dtend', array('year'=> $year, 'month'=> $month, 'day'=> $day, 'hour'=> $hour, 'min'=> $min, 'sec'=> $sec));
    $vevent->setProperty('summary', $task->subject);
    $vevent->setProperty('description', "Description of the task");
    $v->setComponent($vevent);
}

$v->returnCalendar();

?>
```

The problem is, the summary and description for the calendar don't come through, and the description for each event doesn't come through.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the description, but I have found a bug in this in that 'summary' wont output but 'SUMMARY' as the property name WILL output.  Ive been trying myself to get this to work in Google but to no avail.  I do have the 'description' properly the same as yours so I'm not sure why that is not outputting for you.